# After our site graduated I can no longer see or edit our custom close reasons

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, custom-close-reasons

[Pets.SE](https://pets.stackexchange.com/) graduated recently, together with many other sites. While still in Beta we had 2 custom close reasons. Now I took a look at the [Manage community-specific close reasons](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/admin/flags/site-specific-close-reasons) site and all the custom ones disappeared.

There are 0/3 active community-specific close reasons.
There are 0/3 deactivated community-specific close reasons.

However, if I vote to close a question, our custom close reasons are still in the list and I noticed others using them after the graduation. They're probably simply not displayed.

Since this is a site I visit very rarely, the problem might have been there since before the graduation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The link `https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/admin/flags/site-specific-close-reasons` directs you to Pets *Meta*, not the main Pets site. For smaller communities, their Meta sites rarely have the need for community-specific close reasons.

Please have a look at `https://pets.stackexchange.com/admin/flags/site-specific-close-reasons`, I'm pretty sure it will list them.

Comment: Ok, this is embarrassing. I did not expect there to be separate close reasons for Pets Meta.

Comment: This is correct - what is worth noting is that moderators can not *edit* community-specific close reasons, they can only create/approve new ones or retire existing ones. If minor changes need to be made to existing close reasons, you can start a meta discussion on Pets Meta and tag it as status-review. :)